# .htaccess not working properly - get variable

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have (probably) very easy problem to fix. My simple .htaccess does not work as I want, and I can't figure out what's happening.

.htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/$ /index.html?sport=$1 [L]
```

Then when I go to `http://domain.com/soccer/` then run this line in console: `window.location.search.replace( "?", "" );` it gives me nothing while it should give me `sport=soccer` exactly as it is doing while I go to  `http://domain.com/index.html?sport=soccer...

It's probably something easy but the .htaccess is a total mystery for me

question:
How do I make the Rewrite work so when people type in

```
domain.com/soccer/
```

will work exactly as:

```
domain.com/index.html?sport=soccer
```

Some simple explanation (not necessary) would help a great deal so maybe finally I could understand .htaccess..

cheers

Answer (score 0):

If you don't redirect the client to the URL with the query string then you won't be able to access the parameters in javascript.
You can redirect the user with addind `[R]` to your rewrite rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/$ /index.html?sport=$1 [L,R]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/$ /index.html?sport=$1 [L]
```

How it works: take URI, such as `/soccer/`. Strip off the leading / and compare it to the pattern. In the pattern, grab everything (0 or more characters) until you run into a / (do not capture the / here). That is captured into $1, and should be **soccer**. Require that the input end with a /. Note that `http://domain.com/soccer` will NOT match, because it has no trailing /. You may want to make that trailing / optional:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/?$ /index.html?sport=$1 [L]
```

Now that you've successfully matched the pattern and gotten $1, output the rewritten URI, substituting **soccer** for $1:

```
/index.html?sport=soccer
```

The `[L]` flag says that's the last Rewrite rule for now.

Note that you use a * for the repetition count in the pattern. If someone types in `http://domain.com/`, it will match and you will get an empty $1, leading to

```
/index.html?sport=
```

which will probably break. You might want to change from * (0 or more matches) to + (1 or more matches).

Is index actually index.php, or some other script? HTML by itself cannot do anything with a Query String. You might as well give the correct file name here, rather than rewriting it again further along.

Comment: the index is actually an index.html, and there is a preload javascript which preloads different set of images (later on used in some pixel manipulation on canvas) depending on different sport.